# How to make dynamic title/meta in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net c#
I want to know that how can we change title or meta in asp.net web page dynamically.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Page.Title = string.Format("Title changed by code : {0:d}", DateTime.Now);
}
```